# 1D Numpy Array Equivalent to Zipping Previous, Current, and Following Elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I haven't been able to find an answer to this elsewhere.

For a 1D numpy array of random numbers, like `a = np.random.rand(10)`, I want to perform an operation on each element that includes each of its neighbor elements (i.e. the previous and following elements) in the function. So, something like

```py
write = []

for previous_item, current_item, next_item in zip(a,a[1::],a[2::]):
    write += operation_on(previous_item, current_item, next_item)
```

but when I try to do this with those slice operators on a Numpy array, it tells me that `a[1::]`, etc. is a float. Is there a Numpy-Array equivalent to zipping through adjacent elements in an array?

Here's a simple version of what I can't get to work:

```py
from random import randint
import math
import numpy as np

size = 3

def logistic(x,b):
    return b*x*(1-x)

def scheme(l,c,r,strength,b):
    print('neighborhood: ',l,c,r)
    new_center = (1-strength)*logistic(c,b)+(strength/2)*(logistic(r,b) + logistic(l,b))
    return new_center

def eSimple(c,l=None,r=None):
    return c

cml = np.random.rand(size**2)

def evolve(cml, r):
    # encode all
    cml = np.vectorize(eSimple)(cml[:-2], cml[1:-1], cml[2:])
    cml = np.vectorize(scheme)(cml[:-2], cml[1:-1], cml[2:], 0.5, r)

for r in np.arange(3.6, 4.0, 0.05):
    evolve(cml,r)
    print(cml)
```

for some reason, although it correctly generates the neighborhoods, `cml` merely increments its values by a very small (~1e-6) amount each step from their initial random values.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should this only work for 1D numpy arrays?

Comment: I tried your code and if I plug something for operation_on it works for me, though results are a bit boring (write is coerced to an empty array and adding a scalar to an empty array doesn't do much)

Comment: @sphericalcowboy I don't really mind either way -- I just want a way to do it. I'd like to use a 1D Numpy array, not a list, but as it stands I can only figure out a way to do this with lists.

Comment: @JackLynch: Why not a list?

Comment: @sphericalcowboy I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed Numpy Arrays would be faster for assignments? Also I assumed they would be quicker to iterate through before reaching this point haha. Also, I end up reshaping it a certain way with Numpy, but I can just change that

Comment: Please select an answer if any of the ones provided help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `numpy` way of doing this would be

```
write = operation_on(a[:-2], a[1:-1], a[2:])
```

but that only works if `operation_on` is vectorised. For example, if `operation_on(x, y, z)` returns `x*x - np.sin(y) + np.exp(z)` it will work because the individual operations all know how to handle arrays.

If not you can use

```
write = np.vectorize(operation_on)(a[:-2], a[1:-1], a[2:])
```

Note that this will get you the convenience but not the speed of numpy.

Comment: when I run it this way, the values seem to be incrementing by an incredibly small amount, even though function I apply returns `r*x*(1-x)`, with `r` being another parameter, so it seems to fit your vectorisation requirement

Comment: @JackLynch I thought your function takes 3 arguments?

Comment: my bad -- my function takes those three, and applies to the center element a "map" of the other two (that's what I was describing). Here, I'll just edit my answer to post my code

Comment: @JackLynch without knowing your `.encode` method it's still difficult to tell what's going on. Also, as you said "incrementing". There is nothing being incremented here, these should be independent calculations.

Comment: my bad, I added it to my answer. What I mean is that, when I print the list I'm writing to, the values seem to all be incrementing by a small value (maybe 1e-6) with each step instead of changing chaotically, as they  should be

Comment: @JackLynch I don't know. You should just be getting a bunch of random numbers between 0 and 0.9 a bit denser towards 0.9 but that should be it. Are you 100% sure what you posted represents what you tried? Maybe you could post a small sample of a and vlist?

Comment: okay, I'll replicate a simpler version of my code and attach the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136410/discussion-between-jack-lynch-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you probably want the three arrays to be the same length. This means either padding the ends of the arrays, or looping over 8 elements instead of 10. Here is the latter approach:

```
for p, c, n in zip(a[:-2], a[1:-1], a[2:]):
   ...
```

This syntax will work identically for a list or an array. The main difference is that list slices will return copies while array slices are views to the same underlying buffer.

If you insist on using a `for` loop for your processing Instead of vectorising the function, you may get marginal improvement from eliminating zip entirely and using a single 2D array:

```
b = np.stack((a[:-2], a[1:-1], a[2:]), -1)
for p, c, n in b: 
   ...
```

Comment: If I'm not totally mistaken, zip does truncate its arguments to the shortest's length.

Comment: @PaulPanzer. True. I was working on getting a single 2D array out of this mess, but realized it wouldn't help.

Comment: Also, even though the other form works, I think yours is better style. Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with element 1 and end with element -2, i.e. use only elements with two neighbors (a previous and a next element):

```
import numpy as np


def operation(pre, cur, nex):
    return pre + cur + nex  # sum as an example operation


a = np.random.randint(3, size=(10,))  # output easier to see using ints
write = []

for pr, cr, nx in zip(a[:-2], a[1:-1], a[2:]):
    write.append(operation(pr, cr, nx))

print(a)
print(write)
```

Output:

```
[0 2 2 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
[4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```